# Need to fire didSelectRowAtIndexPath from within a UITextField in custom cell

Tags: iphone

I need to fire this function
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}

when the UITextField of a Custom Cell in a UITableView is selected, so far it only fires when the row gets selected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to find out when the user tapped on your field, and at that point fire the -tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: for the field's row, just turn off userInteractionEnabled for that field. The tap will 'fall-through' to the underlying row, which will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Nah that's not want I wanted Ben. I managed to get around it by firing EditBegin and having the UITextField tags as the row number.